# Getting Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063 when trying to lauch in local IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, tfs, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

im running a simple web application testing out the TeamFoundation.Services.Client along side VisualStudio.Services.Common and launching the app via IIS Express is no problem but when I try to do the same using Local IIS I get this error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: 'VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://mytfs:8080.

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource, bool)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

This is the debug profile in which im trying to launch it:
[image]

This is the code where I get the error:

```
internal const string vstsCollectioUrl = "http://myTFS:8080/tfs/MyCollection"; 

//Prompt user for credential
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vstsCollectioUrl), new VssAadCredential("{user}", "{password}"));

//create http client and query for resutls
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VssAadCredential` class by default takes the credentials of the person running the tool and does not honor the username and password parameters actually in `.net core` projects, similar to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/752620/view.html). So you can't use Azure Active Directory Authentication like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#azure-active-directory-authentication-for-rest-services), and it's not recommended to use [AAD Authentication for REST services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#azure-active-directory-authentication-for-rest-services) in [SOAP service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/soapsamples?view=tfs-2018#azure-active-directory-authentication-for-soap-services).

As a workaround you can try windows Authentication:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("http://instanceName:8080/tfs/OrgName/"), new WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx")));
```